# Variable does not exist but compile works, runtime fails

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have inherited a bunch of Access projects.  I found a very strange issue where some form code accesses a variable that does not exist.  The compile works fine, intellisense will auto complete the variable but at runtime I get an error 2465, can't find the field 'xxx' referred to in your expression.

The field most certainly does not exist, there is no variable by that name.

Any ideas why the compiler is not finding the issue?

I think it may have something to do with the query to fill the form.  I think it did have the column XXX at some point, then it was removed.  The compile still works but the run does not.  I'm not sure.

There is no code with this question because the code is not at fault.  If you read the accepted answer below its a 'feature' of Access that the VBA compiler uses the auto generated column names from a record source as variable names, modifying the query breaks this linkage.

Comment: Unclear if you're referring to a variable or to a field (showing your code would probably help), but VBA will merrily compile code with undeclared variables if `Option Explicit` isn't specified. Also late binding (member calls against `Variant` and/or `Object`) will defer to run-time several errors that could otherwise be caught at compile-time or with static code analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention if the var comes up with you type me + "dot" in the given form.
This would reveal important information.

You can also type in the variable name (it it is not a me.dot var) and then hit shift f2, and that should/can jump you to the location of the variable.

However, if this is a me.dot value? then open the form in design mode. Display property sheet, data tab.

Now select and CUT out the forms datasource to your paste buffer. You now must TAB out of the datasource. Now, tab back in, re-paste in the forms datasource, and AGAIN tab out. This forces access to re-generate the "me." members for the form. So, over time it is possible to delete columns and controls on that form, but the "members" are thus no re-generated until such time you do above.

so, the missing detail here is this a me.dot intel-sense, or is this some global var defined in some code module? As noted, if this is a not a me.dot member of a form, then click on that var, and try shift-f2 and see if that finds the variable.

Of course in the vba editor, you can also do a ctrl-f and search the GLOBAL application for all and any occurrences of that variable - and thus such a search of all code would and could again find the origin of that variable.

Comment: This is the answer, The query has been modified without removing it from the record source.  Intellisense still thinks the variable/column exists and will auto-complete.  The VBA compile must use the intellisense tables because the compile will also succeed.  You won't know an error occurred until runtime. Any modification of a record source must include removing and then re-adding the record source.

Comment: Or you can use me!Column name in place of me.Column - as ! (bang) a is runtime resolution of the column(s) in place of me.dot which is a compile time resolution. This "generation" of DOT members is a feature for convenience - but it is at design time, and if your code changes the data source, then it can fail. As a result to reference a column that is NOT on the form as a control? Use me! (bang) in place of me. (dot). If a control on the form exists, then me.dot will always work. If no control is on the form with same name as column of form's data source, then one should use ! (bang).

Comment: So it not really anything to do with inttel-sense. The feature simply generates the .dot members for you, and most thus use that. But as noted, it can let you down, and further as noted the members generation was/is a feature to help new coders and new users of Access. That form represents a class object, and thus the member generation occurs at design time. However, as noted, without a control of same name, then code that changes the forms record source can fail. Using ! (bang) will always work. So, I tend to use ! (bang) when I want to reference columns behind, and use .dot for controls.